# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition not working with onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation, navigator

I'm having a strange issue that I can get the geolocation (immediately) inside the `componentDidMount()` function but when I click the button and execute `geolocateMe()` I get a `PositionError` after 5 seconds.

Anyone has an idea how to make `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` work with an onClick trigger?

Using Chrome 59 and I allowed my application to "Track your location".

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class GetGeolocation extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => { console.log(pos); },
                                        (error) => { console.log(error); },
                                        { timeout: 5000 });
  }

  geolocateMe() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => { console.log(pos); },
                                        (error) => { console.log(error); },
                                        { timeout: 5000 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.geolocateMe()}>Geolocate me</button>
    );
  }
}
```

#### First visit

**console log**

`Position {coords: Coordinates, timestamp: 1496902322562}`

#### Click on button

**console log  (after 5 seconds)**

`PositionError {code: 3, message: "Timeout expired"}`

### EDIT

`navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()` is aso being used inside a higher component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Found the issue.**

Inside a higher component I was using `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()` and this seems to block `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`. The first `getCurrentPosition()` inside `componentDidMount()` was probably executed successfully because of being faster than `watchPosition()`.

Removing `watchPosition()` from the higher component made the onClick function `geolocateMe()` work as expected.